# Shell combining Parameter Expansion

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have the 3 lines of code. How can they best combined possibly into only one call without pushing the results always into the variable.

```
value=$(echo $value) #eliminates LF
value=${value//\"}
value="\"${value%% *}\""
```

Update:

a string which look like that . (The quotes in the string will be used to be pushed in another JSON structure where it has to be quoted. But as the input for $values is already quoted, there is no need to eliminate the quotes to add them later again.)

> ""643
> 645,Segment1_System3""

should be converted into

> ""643""

only if $value does not pop up right as ""643""

Comment: In bash, you typically (with very few exceptions) _can't_ combine PEs. zsh explicitly supports some of this, but it's pretty much a zsh-exclusive kind of thing.

Comment: That said, there are very much better ways to eliminate linefeeds. `echo $value` also expands wildcards and otherwise goes pretty well beyond what you're asking for.

Comment: ...if you describe what you're trying to accomplish with prose rather than code, maybe we can suggest better approaches.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: (also, inserting literal quotes into your data is _often_ a code smell, depending on why it's being done; if you're trying to make a substring be valid JSON, f/e, this is very much inadequate-to-task; likewise, if you're trying to quote a value for inclusion is something eval'd as code in a shell, or for several other typical use cases)

Comment: If you're correctly using the right tools for JSON (`jq`, the Python standard-library `json` module, `jsawk`, etc), then any literal quotes in your data will be changed by those tools to `\"`-style backslash-escaped quotes (because that's the only correct way to represent literal quotes in JSON). If you're not doing that, you have bigger / more serious bugs, because your tools aren't understanding the difference between literal and syntactic quotes; that means they _also_ won't understand things like the need to double up backslashes, or convert tabs to `\t`, or so forth.